# CSS retina and non retina media queries

Tags: html, css, retina-display

I am trying to set up a background image for my website according to different resolutions. I also want to include the retina media queries so that if a retina device accesses my site the proper image will be loaded. The thing is that I always get the highest resolution which is not retina of course... Here is my css

```
 <style>


#background
{
    font-size: large;
    position: relative;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    color: white;

}

  @media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width:1024px) and (orientation : landscape)and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) 
{
    #demo{
    width: 100%;

    min-height: 800px;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position:absolute;
    background-image: url(demo_BG_1024@2x.png);
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width:1025px)
{
    #demo{
    width: 100%;

    min-height: 800px;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position:absolute;
    background-image: url(demo_BG_1024.png);
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width:1024px)
{
    #demo{
    width: 100%;

    min-height: 800px;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position:absolute;
    background-image: url(demo_BG_1024.png);
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width:720px)
{
    #demo{
    width: 100%;

    min-height: 800px;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position:absolute;
    background-image: url(demo_BG_720.png);
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width:320px)
{
        #demo{
        width: 100%;

        height: 100%;
        background-size: 100%;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        position:absolute;
        background-image: url(demo_BG_320.png);
        background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
    } 
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:1` for non-retina.

> NON-Retina.

```
 @media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width:1024px) and (orientation : landscape)and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) 
{
    #demo{
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 800px;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position:absolute;
    background-image: url(demo_BG_1024@1x.png);
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
    }
}
```

> Retina

```
 @media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width:1024px) and (orientation : landscape)and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) 
{
    #demo{
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 800px;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position:absolute;
    background-image: url(demo_BG_1024@2x.png);
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice ;) Why firefox does not display the background now?

Comment: only firefox? It should not work on any browser because i used 1x.png not your 2x.png image for non retina media.

Comment: Can you please provide me a working example as I am totally lost now? I am new to retina sites. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To add on to @BaTmaN 's answer, it most likely didn't work in Firefox bc/ the example code is using webkit prefixes.
For other browsers you would need to use the proper browser prefixes:
eg.

```
only screen and (-moz-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3/2),
only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5)
```

Comment: `min-device-pixel-ratio` is not a standard. The unprefixed version is not supported by any browser. The only useful notation is the one with webkit prefix, add `min-resolution` for other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use media queries, I use retina.js. All you need to do is include the retina.js file and host two versions of the image - `image.png` and `image@2x.png` (for example).

The JavaScript will then check every image on the page and automatically display the high resolution image (`@2x` - Apple's pre-defined identifier) on retina displays if it is available, or display the normal image if not. Non-retina displays will be served the non `@2x` version.

More information here: http://imulus.github.io/retinajs/

Comment: Sorry I downvoted because op explicitly asked for media query and tagged with html, css and retina-display. How could you answer that with a Javascript solution? I don't get it.

Comment: @inta I was providing an alternative option that maybe the op had not considered, and it is an easier way of doing it. For example I was having problems trying to use media queries because I had not heard of retina.js, but it is in fact a much easier way of doing it.